# how to use queryXMLNode in webmethod?

Tags: webmethod

I use software design AG to develop, I need to read a xml file and get it's value. but I don't know how to handle it's  parameter. I made a research claiming that I need to use xpath to read value. I am really confused. any people could tell me the result. thanks....

## I do so many research. but it is hard to find real answer